# how to use XCTestcase in static objc library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, xctestcase

I'm trying to add a XCTestCase to a static library written in ObjC. But I get this errors

```
'XCTest/XCTest.h' file not found
Cannot find interface declaration for 'XCTestCase', superclass of 'MotwinTests'
```

I didn't understand why the XCTestCase is not found in my static library or maybe is not supported with static library?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after a long time stack on this problem, I came to figure out that it's a configuration problem related to search path in Build Setting of the my test target (search path  = OCMockitoIOS and GHUnitTest).
To solve the problem, I just cleared the search path as the following screen:
[image]